# Folder sharing Windows 7 Embedded

Tags: c#, cmd

I work on a project for share the same folder automatically on many Windows 7 Embedded with an application in c# or command line windows. Only the account "Guest" can access the folder (this account have not a password).

- I managed to share the folder in command line on a Computer
  (Windows 7 Enterprise). I used Cacls.

  `CACLS C:\dir /G Guest:F`
- So that the account Guest to access without password, it is necessary :

  - That change the parameter "Turn on password protected sharing" on OFF in the menu "Advanced sharing settings" in 'Network and Sharing Center'.
  - Or delete the account Guest in "Deny access to this computer from the network" in Local Group Policy Editor.

I realized this last method, I used LGPO.exe for export/import settings of "Local Group Policy".

On the test PC (Windows 7 Enterprise) everything works fine but when I try on Windows 7 Embedded PC, nothing works.

Can you help me?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you say more about "nothing works." What does happen? Copy and paste as text any error messages into the question.

Comment: There is no error message. When I import a setting of "Local Group Policy" with LGPO.exe the console does not show me an error message but no change is made. It's the same when I use Cacls